# What is the "struct address_space" that backs a anonymous memory page?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel

In the Linux kernel, there is a field named `mapping` in `struct page`. This field may represent the file that backs the page when it's the buffer cache of the file. It could also be a page that is backed by the device `swap`.

My question is

What is the device `mapping` for an anonymous memory page? Is that some special device as well(say, swap device)? Thank you!

FYI, I'm reading Linux 5.13.

Comment: Are you referring to the member [`struct address_space *mapping`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.13/source/include/linux/mm_types.h#L88)?

Comment: Yes. I just checked... I realized that the mapping field of an anonymous page is NULL, which means there's no conceptual device backing the page...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `->mapping` field of `struct page` can actually point to three different things, and weirdly enough, two of them are *not* a `struct address_space` (despite the type of the field). This is explained [in a comment from `include/linux/page-flags.h`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.13/source/include/linux/page-flags.h#L454):

> - On an anonymous page mapped into a user virtual memory area,
>   `page->mapping` points to its `anon_vma`, not to a `struct address_space`;
>   with the `PAGE_MAPPING_ANON` bit set to distinguish it.  See `rmap.h`.
> - On an anonymous page in a `VM_MERGEABLE` area, if `CONFIG_KSM` is enabled,
>   the `PAGE_MAPPING_MOVABLE` bit may be set along with the `PAGE_MAPPING_ANON`
>   bit; and then `page->mapping` points, not to an `anon_vma`, but to a private
>   structure which KSM associates with that merged page.  See `ksm.h`.
> - `PAGE_MAPPING_KSM` without `PAGE_MAPPING_ANON` is used for non-lru movable
>   page and then `page->mapping` points a `struct address_space`.

When a page is anonymous *and* mapped to userspace, `page->mapping` points to the corresponding `struct anon_vma`, not to a `struct address_space`. The value of the pointer itself is therefore not `NULL`, but trying to get ahold of it using functions such as [`page_mapping(page)`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.13/source/mm/util.c#L689) you will get a `NULL` back. To get ahold of the VMA, a few checks need to be made first (including first checking and removing the flags embedded into `->mapping`). See the functions [`page_get_anon_vma(page)`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.13/source/mm/rmap.c#L485) or [`page_lock_anon_vma_read(page)`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.13/source/mm/rmap.c#L528).